# I want to find files with specific extensions (.pfd, .xls, . ser and .csv) which are 30 days older

Tags: linux

I am struggling to list down all the files in the current directory with .pdf, .xls, . ser and .csv extensions which must be 30 days older.
I am using the command

```
find $Path -maxdepth 1 -mtime +33 -type f \(-iname "*pdf" -o -iname "*xls" -o -iname "*ser" -o -iname "*csv"\) | xargs ls -ltr >> ${LOG_OUT};
```

but i am receiving an error:

> find: paths must precede expression: (-iname Usage: find [-H] [-L]
> [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...]
> [expression]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find $Path -maxdepth 1 -mtime +33 -type f \( -iname "*pdf" -o -iname "*xls" -o -iname "*ser" -o -iname "*csv" \) | xargs ls -ltr >> ${LOG_OUT};
```

you need a `space` after `\(` and before `\)`

Also you do not need `|xargs`, try this:

```
find $Path -maxdepth 1 -mtime +33 -type f \( -iname "*pdf" -o -iname "*xls" -o -iname "*ser" -o -iname "*csv" \) -exec ls -ltr {} \; >> ${LOG_OUT}
```

Comment: thanks ron but i am getting

find: invalid expression; I was expecting to find a ')' somewhere but did not see one.

after inserting a space

Comment: Please check my commands more closely. Or just copy-paste them. You need space before `\)` as well